# Does CPU directly handles Interrupts?

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16

Does CPU directly handles interrupt? or is it the Programmable Interrupt Controller that handles it. I want to know about interaction between PIC and CPU. How they interact? Whether PIC is disabled while CPU is servicing an interrupt.

Comment: The PIC routes interrupts to the CPU.

Comment: @RossRidge AFAIK a PIC is optional

Comment: Did you have a look at the datasheet? What research effort did you perform?

Comment: @m0skit0 It's not optional (something needs to put the interrupt number on the bus), but I don't see the point of your comment, since even if it were optional it wouldn't change the fact that the PIC is used to route interrupts to the CPU.

Comment: @fuz Why would I have asked question if I can easily read the datasheet? I just need summary of details which m0skit0 has provided.

Comment: If you read but did not understand the datasheet, why didn't you tell us what part you don't understand?

Comment: Dear OP, fuz is right. First you need to do your research then ask, not the other way around.

Comment: @RossRidge You're right, I stand corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there 2 types of interruptions: hardware and software. I guess your question is about hardware ones.

> Does CPU directly handles interrupt? or is it the Programmable
>   Interrupt Controller that handles it.

8086 can only handle one non-maskable interrupt (NMI pin). For maskable interrupts (pint INTR), a PIC is needed (8259 and subsequent models and replacements). Note that several PICs can be cascaded together to offer more interrupt lines.

> I want to know about interaction between PIC and CPU. How they
>   interact?

8086 receives an interrupt notification through the INTR input pin, the interrupt number on the data bus, and acknowledges the interruption through the INTA output pin.

> Whether PIC is disabled while CPU is servicing an interrupt.

8259 can receive other interrupts through other IRQ lines that is not the one being serviced. ISR keeps track of which interruption is being serviced, IRR keeps track of pending interruptions, and IMR masks interruptions. Other 8259 models introduce more programmable features.

More details can be found on the technical documentation for both 8086 and 8259s.

Comment: While this is not wrong, it is very obsolete. Since the Pentium, the INTR and NMI pins have been superseded by the LINT0 and LINT1 pins of the APIC. In SMP system, the 8359A is used only briefly at boot, replaced in favour of the IOAPIC. The PCI had a complex routeing system and PCIe mostly use MSI. The topic is very broad, so I understand your narrowing down to the 8086 only (a tag that the OP may have used categorically).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you for your clarifications, but for me, the tag restricts the question to THAT specific CPU. If not, one could also assume that the `intel` tag also means any kind of CPU, and so on.

Comment: @m0skit0 I was looking for 8259 PIC. You got it correctly. Thank You Very Much